# Unable to create property for a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

```
public class Address
{
    public string streetno;
    public string streetname;
    public string suburb;
    public string postcode;
    public Country country;
}
public class Country
{
    public string name;
}

public class Person<A>
    where A : new()
{
    public A address;

    public Person()
    {
        address.country = new Country();
    }
}
```

when i compile the above code i get the following error: 
error CS1061: 'A' does not contain a definition for 'country' and no extension method 'country' accepting a first argument of type 'A' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

any ideas on how I can over come this issue?

Answer (score 7):

Well, first you need to understand the error. What would you expect to happen if we wrote:

```
Person<string> x = new Person<string>();
```

That would create an object with an `address` field of type `string`. Now `string` doesn't have a `country` property, so it doesn't make sense.

It's not clear to me why you want it to be generic to start with, but you *could* add an extra constraint so that `A` has to be `Address` or a derived class (roughly speaking):

```
public class Person<A> where A : Address, new()
```

Now you'll just get a `NullReferenceException` - because you're not creating a new instance of the address... your constructor would need to change to:

```
public Person()
{
    address = new A();
    address.country = new Country();
}
```

Alternatively, for more flexibility you might want to create an `IAddress` *interface* and express the constraint in terms of that, instead of the class... but that's up to you. It's hard to recommend a concrete course of action without more details of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to specific properties of a generic type like that unless you've given a generic type constraint that has those properties. For example, if you declared your class like:

```
public class Person<T> where T : Address, new()
{
    public T address;

    public Person()
    {
        this.address.Country = new Country();
    }
}
```

of course that might defeat the purpose if you only have that address class. It seems odd that this is a generic class where your generic type parameter is an address. Another approach would be to use the dynamic keyword:

```
public class Person
{
    public dynamic address;

    public Person()
    {
        this.address.Country = new Country();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to restrict your type to one that supports the country property. Since using the Address class directly is rather pointless consider using some type of base class /interface.

```
public interface IAddress
{
    public string streetno { get; set; }
    public string streetname { get; set; }
    public string suburb { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public Country country { get; set; }
}

public class Person<A>
    where A : IAddress
{
    public A address;

    public Person()
    {
        address.country = new Country();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably submitted a bad example. This is closer to what I have:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class SomeHeader
    {

    }

    public class SomeParamaters
    {

    }

    public class SomeRequest
    {
        public SomeHeader Header;
        public SomeParamaters Parameters;
    }
}

using SomeNamespace;

namespace MyNamespace
{

    public class Worker<A>
        where A : new()
    {
        public A req;

        public void DoSomeMeaningfulWork()
        {
            req.Header = new SomeHeader();
            req.Parameters = new SomeParamaters();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the classes `SomeXXX` inherit from object and implement `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The reason I chose generics was there are many request,header,paramters,respons,data,error groups. Basically each type of request defines a family of these.

The worker classes - after having written 3 are exactly the same bar the request,header,paramters,respons,data,error.

I was unaware of the dynamic keyword - but it does sound like what i am after as i know exactly the properties that are needed to be called - they are exactly the same and of the same  type.

However, my problem is, I am using .net 3.5 and vs 2008

I have considered interfaces and constraints, but they just dont seem to work for the current problem i am facing.

Comment: I don't see where an interface would not satisfy your requirements, given the code in DoSomeMeaningfulWork. Just put the common properties in that interface.